# How to process bulk actions out of WP_List_Table class in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm extending WP_List_Table in WordPress in my plugin. I'm using the example here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-list-table-example/ as the base for what I'm doing. Now, in the example documentation it says that you can process the bulk actions wherever you want, but I haven't found an example that shows how to do that.

Specifically I want to process them in an `admin_action{$action}` hook, and then redirect back to the table page.

Is this a smart thing to do? Most important, how can I do it? Does someone can provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulk action can be implemented by overwriting the method `get_bulk_actions()` and returning an associated array:

```
function get_bulk_actions() {
  $actions = array(
    'delete'    => 'Delete'
  );
  return $actions;
}
```

You can find a full details step by step guide [here](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/)

### **Edited**

To process your bulk action, yes you can use `admin_action{$action}` hook. If you are using some simple action name(like edit, delete) only thing you need to make sure is, put a request verification code to determine if request is for you or not. Another way to prevent the interference to name your action prefixed with your plugin name like (my_aswam_plugin_edit_action, my_aswam_plugin_delete_action). Because any request with $action=**YOUR_ACTION** will trigger your hook.

> add_action( 'admin_action_**YOUR_ACTION**', 'your_bulk_action_handler_function' );
>
> function your_bulk_action_handler_function() {
>
> ```
>  // Do your stuff here
>  //Make sure you do some check to be sure this request is for you to process
>
> wp_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
> exit();
> ```
>
> }

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @xiidea. I'm afraid though, that I'm not talking about get_bulk_actions() but about process_bulk_action(). In any case, I'm not trying to override the method in my Table_List child class, but to do the processing outside that class. I appreciate your time anyway.

Comment: Indeed, before seeing your changes, I decided to test that same approach, and implemented it as you suggest. I'm using a nonce to verify that is for me to process the form data, and had to do a couple of overrides in the custom List_Table class to make it fit my new way of processing things. In any case, your answer is correct, so I accept it.

Comment: admin_action_YOUR_ACTION  << This is good. It works. But... Do you know how to verify nonce on "users" bulk actions?
check_admin_referer('bulk-users'); always failed.
wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wpnonce'], 'bulk-users'); always return false.

Comment: @vee Could you please check if you are passing the nonce through post or URL query parameter. the  `check_admin_referer('bulk-users')` expect `_wpnonce` passed as query parameter. or for manual check you can also try `wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['_wpnonce'], 'bulk-users');`

Answer (score -1):

here i wrote an alternative method to work with wp_list_table bulk actions.

http://kvcodes.com/2014/05/wp_list_table-bulk-actions-example/

Comment: You might want to give the user a more extensive answer by adding an explanation.

Comment: Hi @varadha, I appreciate your answer, but it doesn't addresses my question. The whole thing is about processing bulk_actions "out" of the child class, wherever you want to do it. In my particular case, that is in a admin_action_hook.